# Fullscreen facebook apps

Tags: facebook, fullscreen

I have noticed that some apps (such as grafati) have a fullscreen button that seems to work quite well but it seems that all of these apps are based on Flash.  Is there any similar Facebook API call that is for non Flash apps?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is a flash script,  not found in Facebook API. Even flash outside of facebook can do that because it is native ActionScript code. Well if you really want your non-flash app fullsreened, press [F11].

It depends of what script language or platform you are using. Maybe yours have its own fullscreen functionality.